# IOS7 Change value of label in different view before segue (Same controller)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 simple views in my Storyboard and both use the same ViewController. I have the following code to switch the the second view...

```
self.labelStatus.text = @"CHECKING";
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccess" sender:sender];
```

*labelStatus is on the second view.

For some reason the labels text is not changing. Can anyone advise why this is?

Comment: do this on prepareSegue method

Comment: So view object are initialized... before perform destination view will no on memory and when you will call perform it will actually create destination view control and will start the process. But for better understanding of ur problem I will suggest some more code.

Comment: Are  you sure label is connect iboutlet...

Comment: It's connected, but always null @C_X. I can do the same method of connecting a label to the first view and it's fine. However the second view just wont seem to connect Code to UI.

Comment: Looks like I cant access the UI in the prepareFor method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccess" sender:sender];
```

//change the label value in `prepareForSegue:` method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LoginSuccess"]) {
        UIViewController *loginVC = segue.destinationViewController;

       //declare the string in .h file and assign it in viewDidLoad in loginVC

        loginVC.labelString = @"CHECKING";
    }
}
```

in `loginViewController.h` file

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *labelString;
```

in `loginViewController.m` file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.labelStatus.text = labelString
}
```

Comment: At this stage (IE in the Prepare method), I don't seem to have access to the UI of the new view (All return null). I can access properties but not the UI

Comment: i have edited the answer, you need to declare the string property in .h file and then assign that string value to your label in loginVC in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Yea, thats the ticket. I've just worked out thats the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise your `destinationViewController` (properties, views, etc) in `prepareForSegue:` method, which is called before segue is executed:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UISegue *)segue {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
        UIViewController *destVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        // do your customisation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit- 
If you need to change the label in the same view controller, then you should modify the label in the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: It's the same ViewController.

Comment: Is it the same class or the same instance?

Comment: You dont seem to have access to the UI from the Prepare method, only properties.